# Laravel/horizon missing css/js build

Tags: php, laravel, build, assets, laravel-horizon

The `/horizon` route from the laravel/horizon package works, but the css and javascript are not loaded.

this is what the road /horizon looks like:

[image]

However, I just installed the package and followed the laravel documentation installation

- composer require laravel/horizon
- php artisan horizon:install
- php artisan optimize
- npm run dev ( and I tried npm run build,...)

this is my config :

- laravel-mix 4.0.7
- laravel/horizon 5.14
- laravel 8.0

Can you help me ?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure assets are included in your application. Try running the following command.

```bash
php artisan vendor:publish --tag=horizon-assets && npm run dev
```

Answer (score 1):

Resolved with variable environment :

```
ASSET_URL=/.
```